# by changing a service from 'outside' angular js the watchers stop working

Tags: angularjs, watch

I am doing so:

```
    angular.element('body').injector().get("myService").somevar = true
```

And somewhere else I'm grabbing it:

```
    $scope.$watch( function () { return myService.somevar; }, function (somevar) {
        console.log(somevar)
    });
```

But the watcher does not trigger, even though if i check the value through the console it has in fact changed

Comment: If you change something outside of the Angular context, you need to manually call `$apply()`.

Comment: ExpertSystem, post as an answer, get the credit you deserve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, you need to use [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply):

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

For example:

```
var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('body'));
var service = element.injector().get('myService');
var scope = element.scope();

scope.$apply(function () {
  service.somevar = true;
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Iy3CiRzDdxFTwVq68JWi?p=preview